# A property of a subset of a topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a non-Hausdorff compact topological space, and $A\subseteq X$ be  an infinite subset of $X $, such that  $a\in \overline{A-\{a\}}$ for every $a\in A $, where $\overline{A-\{a\}}$ is the closure of $A-\{a\}$ in $X$. Is there any equivalent condition for this property of $A$.

Comment: equivalent to no isolated points, i.e., no singleton is open

Answer (score 1):

This equivalent to:

*$A$ does not contain any isolated point in its relative topology*,

or equivalently,

*Every point of $A$ is an accumulation point of A, i.e., for every $a\in A$ and every $U\subset X$ open, with $a\in U$, then $U\cap (A\setminus\{a\})\ne\varnothing$.*

Answer (score 0):

You can assume that every subspace of the kind  $A-\lbrace a \rbrace$ isn' t  compact. Now remember that a closed set in a compact space is compact!

Comment: It’s entirely possible that *every* subset of $X$ is compact: $X$ might have the indiscrete or the cofinite topology, for instance.